# Knockout mapping + computed child elements + "mapping reload" fails

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I wish to use Knockout mapping to generate ViewModel.

```
var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
```

After creating ViewModel I would like to add computed text element.

```
for (var i = 0; i < viewModel.Packages().length; i++) {
    var pack = viewModel.Packages()[i];
    pack.packageClass = ko.computed(function() {
        return this.Height() * this.Depth() * this.Width()
    }, pack);
}
```

Bind the page.

```
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Page is working fine in this state...

But now user would like to "save" and "reload" page.
This would be done using mapping feature which updates ViewModel with new data.

```
data = ko.mapping.toJSON(viewModel);
```

But it is not possible to add again those computed fields before rebinding page. And I will get error that computed element is not found (anymore).

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(data, viewModel);
```

**Am I doing something totally wrong?**

Everything works fine without computed fields or without reloading ViewModel...

**Update: Fiddle updated to work like in solution.**

[Fiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/pylenius/yukAa/)

Comment: I updated fiddle to use latest knockout version, V2.2.0.  Then everything works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a explicit ViewModel

```
PackageViewModel = function(data) {
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);

    this.packageClass = ko.computed(function() {
        return this.Height() * this.Depth() * this.Width()
    }, this);
};
```

then use mappign options like this

```
var mapping = {
   Packages: {
      create: function(options) {
         return new PackageViewModel(options.data);
      }
   }
};

ko.applyBindings(ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping));
```